# Paypal-Django issues

Tags: python, django, paypal

I'm having a few issues getting `paypal-django` synced up.  Everything works perfectly on the development server in the sandbox environment, but when I put it on the productions server, 
the template seems to render a different version than the one I customized and the one that shows up on the development server. This version has no HTML/CSS, just a blank payments form.

In the production environment the `PayPalPro` function renders `pro/payment.html` which I customized just by extending my `base.html`, but that formatting doesnt show up and the payments itself doesn't seem to work anymore. Sorry if this post seems confusing, I'm a little lost with this one. Thanks.

```
#template 

{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        <tbody>
            {% if errors %}<tr><td colspan="2" align="center">{{ errors }}</td></tr>{% endif %}
            </tr>
            {{ form.as_table }}
            <tr><td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" /></td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
</div>

{% endblock %}


#views

    def express_payment(request):
        user = request.user
        cart_subtotal = cart.cart_subtotal(request)

        if request.method == "POST":
            form = PaymentForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                order = form.save(commit=False)
                order.buyer = request.user
                order.transaction_id = order
                order.save()
                if order.pk:
                    cart_items = cart.get_cart_items(request)
                    for item in cart_items:
                        order_item = OrderItem(item=item.item_id, quantity=item.quantity, price=item.item_id.price, order=order)
                        order_item.save()
        item = {
        "amt": cart_subtotal, # amount to charge for item
        "custom": '555', # custom tracking variable for you
        "cancelurl": settings.URL + "error", # error page
        "returnurl": settings.URL + "success"} # success page

        kw = {"item": item, # what you're selling
        "success_url": "/success/"} # redirect location after success, I am not sure but it shouldn't work
        ppp = PayPalPro(**kw)
        return ppp(request)
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code; I don't think the version running is as written.